# Cannot connect to PC in the same network with activated VPN

Tags: ssh, networking, vpn, vnc

I have two computers with Ubuntu 20.04, connected to the same router.
I am running `vino-server` on PC2, and Remote-accessing it with Remmina from PC1.
As soon as I connected PC2 to (Proton)VPN, the remmina client closed.
To use the VPN I installed with `sudo gdebi protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.1-1_all.deb` the client obtained [here](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-vpn-setup/).
Then I launched the client and hit *Quick connect*.

If I try to connect via VNC again, I get in remmina *Unable to connect to VNC server*.
If I disconnect from VPN (from the console in PC2), I can VNC again from PC1 to PC2.

I can always `ssh` from PC1 to PC2, using the same local IP 192.168.0.30 for PC2, regardless of the status of the connection to VPN.

In addition, if I go to the console in PC2, I see in a web browser that my external IP is IP#1, different from IP#2 that I get with `ip a` (an extract shown below).

So my questions are:

1. Is it normal that I cannot connect with VNC (remmina) with the local IP when PC2 is connected to VPN? I think I tried this some time ago, and did not find this issue.
2. Can I fix that? I guess that, given I can ssh, I could setup an ssh tunnel, but so far I mean to use the local IP.
3. Is it normal to get a different "my IP" via web browser and via `ip a`, when connected to VPN?
4. Is there any possible relation between 1 and 3?

**Related**:

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/ProtonVPN/comments/my6d32/split_tunnel/
2. https://protonvpn.com/support/protonvpn-split-tunneling/

---

Extract:

```
[PC2]$ ip a
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ...
    inet 192.168.0.30/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 3556sec preferred_lft 3556sec
4: ipv6leakintrf0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ...
    inet6 ...::/64 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 .../64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: proton0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet <external IP#2>/16 brd xx.xx.255.255 scope global noprefixroute proton0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 .../64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: I bet your VPN client configured your system so that *all* routes (`ip route`) go through the VPN. You need to change that.

Comment: since I really have no idea how you set up your VPN, sadly, I can't.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Could you give any other example of how to do that, with any VPN? That may be very illustrative and guide me.

Comment: no, that sounds like a waste of time, compared to you describing exactly how your VPN connection is established and we then actually solving *your* problem.

Comment: Thanks! which of the four methods is that `gdebi` you mention?

Comment: I don't know ProtonVPN at all, but what it needs to offer you for this to work is called "split VPN", i.e. not *all* traffic goes through the VPN. A little Google suggests ProtonVPN is based on plain OpenVPN, and that should be able to do that. I don't know about your special graphical client, though!

Comment: @MarcusMüller - I will check "split VPN". I understood that selective VPN routing allowed you to handle traffic from the client PC to the internet. 
1) https://superuser.com/questions/983727/route-only-specific-traffic-through-vpn
2) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64319/only-routing-certain-traffic-through-vpn
I didn't know that also affects connectivity to the local IP address 192.168..... to servers running in the same PC. In fact, it doesn't seem to affect connectivity via SSH, only via VNC. I wonder if you have any comment/explanation for that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Thanks to your pointer, I found  1. https://www.reddit.com/r/ProtonVPN/comments/my6d32/split_tunnel/, I still have to check if that provides a solution.
Even in the case "split tunnel" is the feature I would need, it seems not available in Linux.

Comment: It's definitely available on Linux. Source: I'm using OpenVPN to connect to my institution's network in a split VPN configuration. Re: "4 methods": I'm referring to the 4 methods as introduced in the "…obtained here" link you've posted.