# VNC access is not available (but SSH is) when conncted to VPN

Tags: ssh, networking, vpn, vnc

**EDIT**:

I tried setting up an ssh tunnel from PC1 to PC2 with

```
$ ssh -L 5901:localhost:5900 PC2
```

and then connecting VNC with localhost:5901. This worked when PC2 was not connected to VPN, but the VNC connection still broke when connecting PC2 to VPN.

Strange thing, I am trying the same with yet another PC3 with Win 10 (instead of PC1). I am using TigerVNC and OpenSSH under msys2 as the clients. When connecting PC2 to VPN, the VNC connection stays alive.

---

I have two PCs (PC1, PC2) behind a home router, as shown below.

```
PC1 (Ubuntu 20.04.3) -> PC2 (Ubuntu 20.04.3) -> Proton servers     Internet
VNC client (remmina).3..VNC server (vino)
SSH client...........4..SSH server                              ->  Site A
                        VPN client (proton).......VPN server  _/    Site B 
                               |             1                       ^ 
                             2 |_____________________________________|
```

PC2 is sometimes running the ProtonVPN client, which I can connect/disconnect from the VPN (1).
I use PC1 as client of the (3) VNC and (4) SSH servers in PC2, using the local IP 192.168... for PC2 (e.g., `ssh myuser@192.168.0.30`).
When PC2 is connected to the VPN (1), I can still SSH with the same method and IP (4), but I cannot not VNC (3) from PC1 to PC2.
I need to fix that.

1. **Is split tunneling useful for what I need?**

   As I understood it is used to control traffic routing *from PC2* to the web via #1 or #2, so it would not be useful.

In addition:

2. **Is the behaviour I see expected?**
3. **Can it be overcome?**

**Related**:

1. https://serverfault.com/questions/405878/asa-5505-stops-local-internet-when-connected-to-vpn
2. https://serverfault.com/questions/351543/network-is-not-available-even-when-cisco-vpn-client-is-connected-wrong-route
3. [Only routing certain traffic through VPN](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64319/only-routing-certain-traffic-through-vpn)
4. https://superuser.com/questions/983727/route-only-specific-traffic-through-vpn

Comment: Please add the output of `route` on both PCs with and without the VPN running, and the flags and subnet mask for each interface from `ifconfig`.

Comment: @NickMatteo - I had a crash in one of the PCs. I will post what you are asking ASAP.